# Importance of keeping meshes low-poly

Tags: modeling

How important is it to keep meshes low-poly? When I model I feel bad about adding high-poly detail and don't do it because when I started with Blender I read some stuff against high-poly modeling, but now I'm confused.

Comment: It depends on what it's for...

Comment: As long as your machine can handle it, go for it! Don't feel bad about adding details ;-)

Comment: Also make sure you consider what you are creating the object for, games generally have a max poly count per object to keep the fps at a good speed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's completely unimportant, until you hit some limitation. Once you do, you know where it'll hurt, and possibly how to solve it.

A high-poly model can be used to bake bump maps, shadow maps, etc. which can be used to give a low-poly model a high-poly look. So even though you may not use the high-poly version in the end, it still is useful.